# Why there is an additional "\"

Tags: python

I am dealing with two variables, one is metrics name and the other is a number or a string. All of them do not comprise special characters. I want to convert it to JSON format and insert it into a mysql text type column. The result is expected to be:

```
"{\"dau\": 123}"
```

My codes are:

```
for i in range(len(hub_queries['data'])):
    query = hub_queries['data'][i]['content'].format('2019-04-21')
    query_job = bq_client.query(query)
    for  row in query_job:
        k = ""
        for i in range(len(row)):
            if unicode(row[i]).isnumeric():
                ai = "\\\"{}\\\": {}".format(query_job._query_results._properties['schema']['fields'][i]['name'], row[i])
            else:
                ai = "\\\"{}\\\": \\\"{}\\\"".format(query_job._query_results._properties['schema']['fields'][i]['name'], row[i])
            if i != len(row)-1:
                k=k+ai+","
            else:
                k=k+ai+"}"
        metrics.append("{"+k) 
print(metrics)
```

The result returns:

```
'{\\"dau\\": 123}'
```

There are two `\` symbols inside the string. However, when I try:

```
print "\\\"{}\\\": \\\"{}\\\"".format(1,2)
```

It returns as expected:

```
\"1\": \"2\"
```

So why there is an additional `\`? How to get rid of it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Since `\ ` is used to encode special characters, e.g. `\n`, `\t`..., `\ ` itself is encoded with a double `\\ `. This is just representation, it's "virtual" you don't need get rid of it...

Comment: How does your string look like?  The one you want to convert!

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh Thanks for your reply. Sorry I did not make it clear. Actually, it's two variables, one is a string like "dau" the other is a number or a string, like 123. The  result is expected to be `\"dau\": 123`

Comment: Could you update your question with this information?

Comment: Stop trying to build JSON manually. Just build a dict and `json.dumps` it. It'll handle all the escaping correctly for you, leaving you with the much simpler task of understanding why it's correct, as opposed to your current combined task of figuring out what "correct" looks like *and* producing correct output.

Comment: Refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C

Answer (score 0):

Since the \ character is a special character, it needs to be escaped in order to be printed. So the first \ escapes the second \, while the third \ escapes the double quotes character.

You don't need to get rid of it, since it prints as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library

```
print(json.loads("{\"dau\": 123}"))
#{'dau': 123}
print(json.dumps({'dau': 123}))
#{"dau": 123}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am using pymysql to insert the json to a text column. The value should be written with `\` to concat the sql sentence: `insert into xxx (column) values ("{\"dau\": 123}")`

Comment: Yes, `json.dumps` will convert your dictionary to string and you should be able to insert it!